# Detect fingerprints on Androids not running API level 23?

Tags: android, xamarin

Is it possible to detect fingerprints on Androids not running API level 23?

Comment: There is zero point in a device having a fingerprint scanner, but an Android version lower than 6 (API level 23)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Fingerprint Authentication requirements in the [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fingerprint-authentication/), this is not possible:

> Fingerprint Authentication requires Android 6.0 (API level 23) or
>   higher and a device with a fingerprint scanner.